# trying to create a compass file

Tags: rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I installed compass with:

```
    sudo gem install compass
```

and version 0.12.2 gem installed, but when I did

```
    compass version
```

or

```
    compass create myfilename
```

I get "command not found". I tried uninstalling and reinstalling and I'm still stuck on the same thing.

All of this from /Users/mycomputer. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6):

Your gem executable directory does not appear to be in your `$PATH`. This may not be the best way to remedy this, but it's pretty direct. Hopefully other members will help improve the answer.

To remedy this, find your gem executable directory:

```
$ gem environment
```

and look for the `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY` line like this:

```
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/mycomputer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@foo/bin
```

Double check that it isn't already in your `$PATH` by looking for it when you run:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

If you don't see your `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY`, edit (or create) `.profile` in your home directory adding (or modifying):

```
export PATH="/Users/mycomputer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@foo/bin:$PATH"
```

Now reload your `.profile` to update your `$PATH` and check that your `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY` is present and try running `compass` again.

```
$ . ~/.profile
$ echo $PATH
/Users/mycomputer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@foo/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin...
$ compas --version
Compass 0.12.2 (Alnilam)
```

Hope this gets you on your way. Managing gems and paths can be a pain. Do what works for you. You might look into [RVM](https://rvm.io/) so you don't have to `sudo` install gems, but I digress.

Comment: Thanks Maxbeatty. I'll try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: guys, be careful you don't accidentally leave off $PATH when redefining the path otherwise you'll lose your other paths! (a noob mistake, but I just made it) I found this helpful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Comment: This worked brilliantly, after some failed attempts of editing .bashrc and .bash_profile, this answer pointed me in the right direction of .profile, so thank you! Terminal newbies: this is the command I used to edit .profile from terminal `vi ~/.profile`